# Why was Peter Parker's passport censored in the trailer?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In the just released [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUFmhKpZKlE) for [*Spider-Man: Far From Home*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6320628/) we get a shot of Peter Parker's passport

[image: Passport]

but **the years seem to have been censored**.

I thought maybe they don't want to spoil when exactly this movie takes place, before or after *[Avengers: Endgame](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/)*.

However, I was under the impression that it was already revealed that it takes place after "Endgame", and in the **[official poster](https://twitter.com/SonyPictures/status/1085172249168998401)** there is a stamp

[image: Poster]

and it says: **Berlin, Germany, Arrived 24 Jul 19** 
(btw, the actual release date in Germany is the [first week of July](http://www.filmstarts.de/kritiken/222291.html), so the date is not referring to that)

Why were the years in the passport blanked out?

Comment: Probably for the same reason as you might not see the years on Uncle Ben's gravestone. Tying down the story to a specific year will make it seem less realistic when Peter Parker's still in his early 20s in 2063. (Because redoing his origin umpteen times won't tip us off to an issue, nor will pop culture references).

Comment: @RDFozz - A couple of months ago Marvel __[has released an official timeline](https://screenrant.com/mcu-timeline-official/)__ that actually does say in which years their movies take place, e.g. __Spider-Man: Homecoming__ is set in 2016 (even though the movie was released in July 2017). - And as I mention, the official poster for the sequel implies that it takes place around July 2019.

Comment: Obviously they just wanted to keep *some* element of mystery involved in the timing of the movie and how it relates to *Endgame* for those people who won't look as closely as you.

Comment: Fact is though, since we see Pete collect his passport it must have been issued in July 2019 by deduction.

Comment: Interestingly though, the arrival date for **London is also 24th July 2019** so that date may not be relevant at all.

Comment: @Paulie_D - The issue date on the passport, __19 July__, would fit with the __24 July__ on the poster, since we see him get a new passport before he goes on the trip. - So why are they putting July 24th 2019 on the poster but then redact July 19th 2019 in the trailer. And if the movie doesn't take place in 2019, why put it on the poster?

Comment: As i said - Obviously they just wanted to keep some element of mystery involved in the timing of the movie for the  trailer and how it relates to Endgame for those people who won't look as closely as you at the poster

Comment: A couple of months ago __Peter Parker's passport, from the time he traveled to Germany in "Civil War", [surfaced on the internet](https://twitter.com/getfandom/status/1027934674058801152) and it does have full dates.__ But it's not clear to me where that image comes from (it doesn't look like a screenshot from the movie), so it could be fake.

Comment: I don't really understand, why **none** of the answers have positive rating.

Comment: @VerNick Because none of them actually **definitively** answer the question. They  all speculate...without evidence.

Comment: And, having seen the movie, Peter definitely didn't get any sort of border stamp when he arrived in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> Now granted, the date could just be an intentional omission from the
>   trailer and we’ll see it in the final product. Don’t forget, remember
>   in the second trailer for Captain America: Civil War when we saw the
>   two sides of heroes running towards each other? You’ll recall that
>   Spider-Man was on Team Iron Man, but he wasn’t seen running alongside
>   Stark and the others… in the trailer. But he was there in the finished
>   version. The same could easily be applicable here. Keeping the year
>   off would keep fans in suspense as to when Far From Home takes place
>   even though, again, there’s already official clarification that this
>   is after the events of the two recent Avengers films that precede it.

[Source](https://heroichollywood.com/spider-man-far-from-home-timeline/)

Comment: You've been asked several times to give attribution to quotations or other content - please don't wait until someone points it out.

Comment: Regardless, this does NOT answer WHY the date has been left off. It just repeats someone else's idle speculation.

Answer (score -1):

Marvel made a real mess with timelines in the previous Spider-Man movie, as explained [here](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/official-mcu-timeline-retcons-spider-man-homecoming-time-jump/).

It makes total sense that in order to avoid such a mess in their new movie, they simply remove any "hard evidence" for exact dates in the movie itself, so they can put any date they want at later time.

The official poster just announce when the movie arrives to theaters, and I don't think the passport timestamps there will be displayed in the movie itself.

Comment: The release date of the movie is at the bottom of the poster, and it's __not__ July 24th. - And as you point out, "Homecoming" already made a mistake with the "8 years", so one would think that this time around they'd be more careful. Therefore it would be odd to put the date "July 24th 2019" on the poster, even though the movie takes place e.g. in 2017 or 2018.